# cx_freeze can't import JSONDecoder

Tags: python, json, cx-freeze

The following python script runs fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import simplejson

print str(simplejson.loads('{"a": "abc"}'))
```

Then after freezing it:

```
cxfreeze test.py --target-dir dist

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 29, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import simplejson as json
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    from decoder import JSONDecoder, JSONDecodeError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 29, in <module>
    NaN, PosInf, NegInf = _floatconstants()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 21, in _floatconstants
    _BYTES = '7FF80000000000007FF0000000000000'.decode('hex')
LookupError: unknown encoding: hex
```

This wouldn't help:

```
cxfreeze test.py --target-dir dist --include-modules simplejson
```

And neither did switching from simplejson to json help.

It seems to give no errors when it is freezing the simplejson part:

```
P simplejson                /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py
m simplejson._speedups      /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/_speedups.so
m simplejson.decoder        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py
m simplejson.encoder        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py
m simplejson.ordered_dict   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/ordered_dict.py
m simplejson.scanner        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/scanner.py
```

Comment: You need to include the module `encodings.hex_codec`. I've opened [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/17/hooks-python-2-json-simplejson-dynamically) to get this done automatically.

Comment: If you put that in an "answer" then I'll accept it. It runs now. It only gives this error:  Exception KeyError: KeyError(140052806182656,) in <module 'threading' from '/dist/test/threading.pyc'> ignored

Comment: I just tried to replicate this, and I couldn't. I'm not sure what's different between your Python installation & mine (I tried with 2.6.8 and 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reposting as an answer)

You need to include the module `encodings.hex_codec`. I've opened [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/17/hooks-python-2-json-simplejson-dynamically) to get this done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

add:

*from encodings import hex_codec*

and add *-m encodings* when using freeze.py to build.
It works on my side.